# Sound Cloud Manager Mass Re post Software with File Path

Tags: soundcloud

I have little confusion or may be i don’t have knowledge to how to operate Sound Cloud Manager Mass Repost Software.

Sound Cloud Manager 2.1.6.8 Mass Repost have one input field that’s name "Track URL or File paths containing  multi-pal track URLs". Its working fine for  single track  URL but as per input field suggest you can put File paths containing  multi-pal track URLs.

Here i am totally confusion . How can i put File paths containing  multi-pal track URLs ? I don’t have any solution.

I created a file contain multipal tracks URLs with comma separated uploaded on my server. Provide path in Input field but Not success. Getting Invalid File URL

Any help will be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are referring to soundcloudmanager.com, or any site/service that claims it can mass repost/like/follow/unfollow, then your in for a treat.... soundcloud has developed methods to prevent such actions (thank you soundcloud).

what the below doesnt mention is that each time you are blocked, the time until the block is removed increases. so the more you do it, the longer you wait each time.

simply put, do not like/repost/etc faster than the time it takes to listen to said track or you may be subject to being banned from using that feature.

from http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1001356-what-have-i-been-blocked-for-

What have I been blocked for?
We have on-site limits in place to encourage the growth of genuine, close-knit communities around creators’ tracks. These limits look for accounts which appear to be using a feature in a way other than it was intended, and can block access to that feature.

You can be blocked from accessing specific feature(s) on-site if you are doing any of the following:

You’re posting similar comments or messages from your account (avoid copy and pasting, or sending comments or messages with the same links over and over)

You’re following a lot of accounts in a short time period

You’re following a lot of people you recently unfollowed

You’re liking or reposting a lot of tracks in one day (make sure you listen to any sound before liking, or reposting it)

You’re liking or reposting a lot of tracks you recently removed from your likes or reposts

You’re contributing your sounds to a lot of groups in a short time period

A number of community members have manually flagged your account, messages or comments as spam

If you keep getting warnings about your activity, you may be blocked.

Although doing this might be a good way to get your tracks out there, it can be frustrating for other members of the community. You will get much more value out of SoundCloud by finding like-minded people in the community. To do this, slow down, be selective, and keep things personal.